# How to take focus/control out after selecting something from the dropdown list - Mat-Autocomplete Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using mat autocomplete from angular material, the  thing that I want to achieve is that I want to take the focus out of input box to outside once I select any option from the dropdown list. By default, it doesn't do it. I have attached a screenshot where you can see after selecting an item, cursor is still blinking in input box. Once the auto focus out is achieved the input box will have different background color and other CSS settings which I want to apply.

[image: screenshot]

Could you please help me out here in this?

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9webad?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html)

Thank you

Comment: In your stackblitz it definitly auto closes in my browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome @DerHerrGammler

Comment: same in chrome. In my case the autocomplete from your stackblitz closes.

Comment: @DerHerrGammler what is the solution then ?

Comment: there is no issue so also no solution. did you try other browser or other computers? I can't help you because i didnt have the problem on my system